# Django ckeditor pdf files upload

Tags: python, django, pdf, file-upload, ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor==5.3.1 and django==1.11.2. I need to upload non-image file. I need to pdf files upload. But I can't not find solution for this (for example pdf icon in editor panel).

Please hint where I can find this.

My model:

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

    class Event(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        date = models.DateField()
        text = RichTextUploadingField()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = True
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Simple',
        'toolbar_Simple': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['Image', 'Update', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'uploadwidget'],
        ],
        'autoParagraph': False,
        'shiftEnterMode': 2,
        'enterMode': 2,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to upload image files, then you can upload PDF files also.
Click on Link icon and a popup will open.
Click on upload tab and you can upload file.
Link to file will be available in first tab.

[image]

Comment: In my case I get: "Invalid file type." in the response (while .png are accepted)

Comment: The PDFs are blank when uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

My most-recent encounter with this – using current CkEditor software – is even stranger:  a PDF-file upload gets converted to ann **image** of its first page!